# Wordpress sorting posts by date and title using a dropdown

Tags: php, wordpress, sorting, custom-wordpress-pages, query-variables

I'm trying to set up a `drop-down` that would sort my posts by Newest to oldest and Alphabetical.

This is what I have so far:

I'm declaring an empty variable, then a form where I can change the contents of this empty variable.

***This part doesn't work***

```php
<form method="GET">
  <select name="orderby" id="orderby">
    <option value="<?php echo ($order = 'date'); ?>">Newest to Oldest</option>
    <option value="<?php echo ($order = 'title'); ?>">Alphabetical</option>
    <button type="submit">Apply</button>
  </select>
</form>
```

And declaring the query where I pass the variable `'orderby' => $order`

***This part works (I'm getting a list of all the posts and changing the query manually works as well)***

```
$wpb_all_query = new WP_Query(array('post_type'=>'post', 'posts_per_page'=>-1, 'order'=>'ASC', 'orderby'=> $order)); ?>

if ( $wpb_all_query->have_posts() ) :
<ul>


<?php while ( $wpb_all_query->have_posts() ) : $wpb_all_query->the_post(); ?>
    <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
<?php endwhile; ?>

</ul>
<?php endif;?>
```

How can I make this work?

Thank you in advance for the help!

Comment: I'm not experienced with WordPress, so I don't know what kinds of operations it can do in the background, but I don't see you assigning the value of the submitted drop-down to the variable. Doing `<option value="<?php echo selected($order = 'date'); ?>">` will perform the assignment *immediately* (while page is being rendered). So `$order` will always have the value of `title` (because that's the last command executed that does the assignment).

Comment: @El_Vanja Oh okay thank you for explaining! Any ideas how I can assign it then?

Comment: First off, `<option value="<?php echo ($order = 'date'); ?>">` should just become `<option value="date">`, with no PHP involved. Next, in the script that handles the form submit, you would access `$_GET['orderby']` to receive the submitted value.

Comment: @El_Vanja Can't get it to work. Provide a code snippet if you can. thx!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So your html form would be something like this:

```html
<form method="GET">
    <select name="orderby" id="orderby">
      <option value="date">Newest to Oldest</option>
      <option value="title">Alphabetical</option>
    </select>
    <button type="submit">Apply</button>
</form>
```

Then check which option, user selected using `isset` and `$_GET['orderby']`. Then based on the value returned, you could set your custom query! So your custom query would be something like this:

```php
$custom_orderby = isset($_GET['orderby']) ? sanitize_text_field($_GET['orderby']) : "";

if(!empty($custom_orderby) && "title" == $custom_orderby):
  $custom_query = new WP_Query(array(
    'post_type'=>'post',
    'posts_per_page'=>-1,
    'orderby'=> "title",
    'order'=>'ASC',
    ));
endif;

if(!empty($custom_orderby) && "date" == $custom_orderby):
  $custom_query = new WP_Query(array(
    'post_type'=>'post',
    'posts_per_page'=>-1,
    'orderby'=> "date",
    'order'=>'DESC',
    ));
endif;?>

<ul>

<?php while ( $custom_query->have_posts() ) : $custom_query->the_post(); ?>
    <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
<?php endwhile; ?>

</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to write this. It wasnt  rocket science from the beginning, but it's a smart way of doing it.



May I add there's an error in your code, as you should be for the query in the loop:

`<?php while ( $wpb_all_query->have_posts() ) : $wpb_all_query->the_post(); ?>
    <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
<?php endwhile; ?>`

Comment: That's right, i just updated my answer. I had used your variable name instead of mine because of ```copy/pasting```! I'm glad it helped.